# How would you calculate the percent in time saved from months to hours?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

I'm trying to turn what I did in my last job into a quantifiable metric. I am in need of a bit of guidance.

If it used to take [company x] two months to make push out a new feature, and now it only takes about an hour. What percent increase in time saved would that be?

Comment: The time saved is $2$ months minus $1$ hour.

The percentage decrease in time required is $(2$ months minus $1$ hour$)\div(2$ months)$\times100\%.$

Comment: Convert the 2 months into hours. The number of actual hours one would work in that time. Then use ryang’s suggestion.

Comment: For a quantifiable metric, I would simply state that it used to take two months and now takes about an hour. I would also try to be as clear as possible about what it was that happens now in an hour. What exactly does "push out" mean? Does it mean the feature gets installed and used at all customers' sites? None of this is mathematics, it's just communicating the facts that would be of interest to your audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, convert 2 months into hours.

There are 365 days in a year and 12 months in a year, so on average a month has $\frac{365}{12}$ or 30.42 days. A day has 24 hours, so each month has on average $30.42*24$ or about 730 hours. 2 months is therefore 1460 hours.

To find the percent change in time, we first find the total change in time,
then divide by the original amount of time, and finally multiply by 100%.

$$\frac{1460-1}{1460}*100\%=\frac{1459}{1460}*100\%\approx 99.9\%$$

The time required has therefore decreased by about $99.9\%$! You could also say that you now save $99.9\%$ of the previous amount of time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Two months is about 9 weeks, and a typical work week is 40 hours. Two months is therefore the equivalent of about 360 hours worked.

Comment: That's true, but which number to use depends on what metric the asker is hoping to create. For the total time from when they are assigned to make a new feature to when it is released, we would use 2 months = 1460 hours. This statistic might be useful to, say, a client who only cares about the total wait time, not the hours worked. A boss on the other hand who cares about productivity per paid hour would certainly prefer to use 2 months = 360 hours, as this would reflect how much more productive the workers are.